# Try {} catch {} on API call or handle differently?

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, laravel-5

In a Laravel 5.2 app, I'm trying to figure out the most elegant way to handle exceptions when those exceptions are thrown by API calls of external services. These shouldn't stop the program from continuing, because there are other parts of the app that still can be run afterwards that can be done even without the problematic API call.

E.g. currently I have

```
try {
    $statistics->results = $api->call($parameter);
    $statistics->status = Statistic::SUCCESS;
} catch (ExternalApiCallException $e) {
    $statistics->results = null;
    $statistics->status = Statistic::API_CALL_ERROR;
}
```

I was thinking of using Laravel's `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` and using

```
if ($e instanceof ExternalApiCallException $e) {
    Log::warning("API Call didn't work");
}
```

but then I wouldn't be able to set the status of the statistics there, because `Handler.php` wouldn't have access to it. Is there a better way or are try-catch-blocks the way to go here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try-catch-finally is definitely a good approach here. In your case API exceptions are localized and should not appear globally (I presume), so I would opt for keeping logic in one place and not putting exception handling as a condition in Handler.php file. In my opinion Handler.php should be used as a last resort option, to style and report otherwise uncaught and unexpected exceptions. For all other cases where exceptions are not critical or even expected, local try {} blocks are easier to maintain, as important parts of the code are not hidden from developer in another file.

Do not forget that you can also use finally {} block, which will be executed after both try{} and catch{} blocks, no matter if the exception was triggered or not.

```
try
{
    // run this first
}
catch (ExternalApiCallException $e)
{
    // in case something went wrong
}
finally
{
    // this runs after everything else
}
```